# Visual Studio 2010 Cannot Use System.Threading.Tasks;

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to execute some processes in parallel. and it is my first time doing that, upon trying :
using System.Threading.Tasks;
Tasks will be underlined in red saying :

```
The Type or namespace name "Tasks" does not exist in the namespace System.Threading(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

how do i resolve that!?

Comment: thanks alot guys! it turned out i was using the 3.5 framework! 
Now it works Thanks :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your project target .NET 3.5 or lower, perhaps? `System.Threading.Tasks` was introduced in .NET 4 - just using Visual Studio 2010 isn't enough; you need to target the appropriate framework. (Fortunately it *is* in the .NET 4 client profile, which is often a little "gotcha" for some other types.)

Likewise Silverlight hasn't *yet* got the TPL, although IIRC it's coming in Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are targeting .NET 4.0 in the properties of your project. TPL is not available in previous versions of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Target `Framework to 4.0` of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add it by right clicking on add reference button in visual Studio?